# How to fill a cell defined in a loop with text entered in user form opened in the loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So the title is a bit confusing im sure. I have the loop seen below where the range "notes" is defined. You can also see that in the loop twords the bottom of the code a user form is opened under certain conditions. That user from has a text box, when the command button "submit" on the user form is clicked I want the text entered in the text box on the user from to be filled to the cell currently defined as "notes". Im not sure how to do this.... The code otherwise works.

```
Dim OP As Date
Dim AC As Date
Dim UE As Date
Dim Act As Date
Dim today As Date
Dim notes As Range
Dim OPs As Range
Dim UEs As Range

Dim i As Integer
Dim message As Integer

For i = 0 To 49

today = Date
OP = Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(i + 23, 11).value
Act = Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(i + 23, 13).value
UE = Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(i + 23, 12).value
Set OPs = Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(i + 23, 14)
Set UEs = Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(i + 23, 15)
Set notes = Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(i + 23, 16)



'Filling Original Plan Status

If OP < 1 Then GoTo FillUE 'Goes to the Updated Estimates Calculation if Origonal Plan Contains No Date

    If Act <= OP Then
        notes.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        OPs = "On Time"
    End If
        If Act > OP Then
            OPs = "Miss"
        Else
            If Act < 1 And today > OP Then
                 OPs = "Incomplete"
            End If
                If Act < 1 And today <= OP Then
                    OPs = "OK"
                End If
            End If




'Filling Updated Estimate Status

FillUE:

If UE < 1 Then GoTo NextLine 'Goes to the next row if Origonal Plan Contains No Date

    If Act <= UE Then
        UEs = "On Time"
    End If
        If Act > UE Then
            UEs = "Miss"
        Else
            If Act < 1 And today > UE Then
                UEs = "Incomplete"
            End If
                If Act < 1 And today <= UE Then
                    UEs = "OK"
                End If
            End If
'Notifying user to fill out notes if a "miss" or "incomplete" is detected

If InStr(UEs, "Miss") > 0 Or InStr(OPs, "Incomplete") > 0 Or InStr(UEs, "Incomplete") > 0 Then
    notes.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 200, 0)
        If notes = "" Then
            UserForm2.Show

        End If
End If

NextLine:
Next
```

Comment: `notes.value = UserForm2.<Name of Textbox>.Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as a matter of best practices, `Goto` should really be avoided outside of conditionally exiting a deeply nested loop. You could do this by switching

```
If x < 1 Then Goto someLine
    'Do Stuff
someLine:
```

to

```
If x > 0 Then
    'Do Stuff
End If
```

To answer your question, since your user is just inputting data and submitting, could you use an `InputBox` instead of showing an entire userform every iteration? So your entire code (starting at your `For-Next` Loop) would read

```
For i = 0 To 49

    today = Date
    OP = Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(i + 23, 11).Value
    Act = Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(i + 23, 13).Value
    UE = Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(i + 23, 12).Value
    Set OPs = Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(i + 23, 14)
    Set UEs = Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(i + 23, 15)
    Set notes = Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(i + 23, 16)

    'Filling Original Plan Status

    If OP > 0 Then
        If Act <= OP Then
            notes.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            OPs = "On Time"
        ElseIf Act > OP Then
            OPs = "Miss"
        Else
            If Act < 1 And today > OP Then
                 OPs = "Incomplete"
            ElseIf Act < 1 And today <= OP Then
                OPs = "OK"
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'Filling Updated Estimate Status

    If UE > 0 Then
        If Act <= UE Then
            UEs = "On Time"
        ElseIf Act > UE Then
            UEs = "Miss"
        Else
            If Act < 1 And today > UE Then
                UEs = "Incomplete"
            ElseIf Act < 1 And today <= UE Then
                UEs = "OK"
            End If
        End If

    'Notifying user to fill out notes if a "miss" or "incomplete" is detected

        If InStr(UEs, "Miss") > 0 Or InStr(OPs, "Incomplete") > 0 Or InStr(UEs, "Incomplete") > 0 Then
            notes.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 200, 0)
            If notes = "" Then
                notes = InputBox("Type Notes", "Notes")
            End If
        End If
    End If

Next
```

**Edit:**

For cleaner code, you could combine some of your `If-End If` into `If-ElseIf-End If`, which I've edited my answer to reflect.

Comment: The code you posted didn't work perfectly as it only fills cells with "On Time" or "Miss" but the input box thing was helpful! I did not know about that so thank you!